# Исполнитель Редактор

Tags: python

Исполнитель Редактор получает на вход строку цифр и преобразовывает её. Редактор может выполнять две команды, в обеих командах v и w обозначают цепочки символов[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я правильно понял алгоритм, то код выглядит так:

```
i = 300
while True:
    i += 1

    text = '5' * i

    while '555' in text or '888' in text:
        index = text.find('555')
        text = text if index == -1 else (text[:index] + '8' + text[index + 3:])

        index = text.find('888')
        text = text if index == -1 else (text[:index] + '55' + text[index + 3:])


    count5 = text.count('5')
    count8 = text.count('8')

    if count5 > count8:
        print(i)
        break
```

и ответ 303

чисто теоретически опять таки можно решить следующим образом:

очевидно, что с заменой только слева направо подстрок мы можем получить только следующие варианты:

```
855
8
885
85
88
8855
55
```

(не возможны варианты типа 858..., потому что меняем цифры строго слева направо и не возможен вариант `'5'` - его неоткуда сформировать (ведь `'888'` всегда меняется строго на `'55'`)

из которых по условию нас устраивает только `855` и `55` (кол-во восьмерок и пятерок от 0 до 2 определяется как раз тем, что мы заменяем тройки этих цифр, т.е. модель по 3)

как несложно понять все приведённые выше строки будут повторяться с периодом  7

теперь, когда у нас есть периодичность начнем с самого нуля - рассмотрим строки от 1 символа и выше:

строка `'5'` нам не подходит - ее нет среди 7 возможных вариантов

берем следующую строку `'55'` - ее размер 2, теперь осталось решить задачу

```
2 + 7 * x > 300
```

откуда

```
x = 47
2 + 7 * 47 = 303
```

задача решена не прибегая к программированию

Comment: Как то слишком замудрённо и умно

Comment: добавил некоторые теоретические выкладки

Comment: код немного сложный из-за требований менять только 1 тройку за раз слева

Comment: text = text if index == -1 else (text[:index] + '8' + text[index + 3:])

Что это значит? И можно эту часть как то облегчить?

Comment: ну это вместо того, чтобы не писать `if index != 1 text = text[:index] + '8' + text[index + 3:]` - мне больше однострочные записи нравятся

Comment: ещё раз огромное спасибо

Comment: я там чуть облегчил теоретическую часть для понимания - можете посмотреть как за 1 минуту без программирования можно решить вашу задачу

Comment: без программирования выглядит легче, но к сожалению нужно на питоне

Comment: text = text if index == -1 else (text[:index] + '8' + text[index + 3:])
text = text if index == -1 else (text[:index] + '55' + text[index + 3:])

Я не до конца понимаю, что вы тут делаете
Если индекс -1, то прибавляете?

Comment: если индекс -1, то ничего не делаю - получается text = text - т.е. строга остается неизменной

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо